# Why is Map.Entry.getValue unknown in java's javascript engine?

Tags: java, javascript, scripting

```
@Test
public void testB() throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String script = "function one(map){\n" + "for(entry in map){\n"
            + "entry.getValue();\n" + "entry.getKey();\n" + "}}";
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put("keyOne", "valueOne");
    String functionName = "one";

    engine.eval(script);

    Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;

    inv.invokeFunction(functionName, map);
}
```

Stacktrace

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: 
Cannot find function getValue. (<Unknown source>#3) in <Unknown source> at line number 3
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.invoke(RhinoScriptEngine.java:184)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.invokeFunction(RhinoScriptEngine.java:142
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I assume there's something I'm not aware of that I need to do to make it work that I can't find documented.

Comment: my javascript's a bit rusty, looks like you are expecting map with a key and value, is that supported ...

Comment: In javascript, everything that is not a scalar is a map(sort of), but something appears to be lost in translation, either on my part, or on the scripting engine's part(I'm assuming the former).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to loop over the [`entrySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) of the map after getting it as an array  via [`map.toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29).
Then, map[entry] is the [Entry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) object, with [`getKey()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey%28%29) and [`getValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29) methods.
Intuitive once you know what to do.

```
@Test
public void testC() throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String script = "function one(map){\n"
            + "var entries=map.entrySet().toArray();\n"
            + "for(entry in entries){\n"
            + "print( entries[entry].getKey());\n"
            + "print( entries[entry].getValue());\n" + "}}";
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("keyOne", "valueOne");
    String functionName = "one";
    engine.eval(script);
    Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
    inv.invokeFunction(functionName, map);
}
```